# Why can't we replace the multi-head attention layer in transformers by a single head with sigmoid function?

Tags: neural-networks, transformers, attention

I know that the reason we use multi-head attention in transformers instead of only single head is to attend to different parts of the input instead of just only one part.

In attention we use softmax function to give attention weights to every input token. We can't attend to different parts of the input using one attention head because of the softmax function.

but what if we used sigmoid function instead of softmax?
**For example:**
If one token in a sentence wants to attend to the first token and the last one. If we used only one-head attention with softmax, It would give approximately .5 attention weights to the first and last token and that's not right so we solve this by using multi-head attention.
Can't we also solve that issue by using sigmoid to give (approximately) atttention weight value of 1 to the first and last tokens?

Comment: This sounds like it stems from a misunderstanding of how attention already works. ("we solve this by using multi-head attention" isn't quite true.) But yes, if you want to constrain the weights to be between 0 and 1, this would work. It's just not clear why you'd do this—softmax forces your model to learn tradeoffs of importance. With sigmoid, (a) there's an identifiability issue and (b) there's no reason for the model not to just weight all positions as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question when I read "Attention is all you need" paper.

The reason, in my opinion, is optimization-related.

Suppose we are computing the attention between 2 sentences x_1, ..., x_n and y_1, ..., y_m.

We will create a nxm attention matrix that we need to optimize.

When using softmax, we need to optimize n values only, because for each row, we need to push one of the m value up which will automatically push down the remainings.

With sigmoid, we need to optimize nxm values, because they are independant.

So even if we use h heads with the softmax attention, we will have an easier optimization problem, in comparison to using a single head with sigmoid.

This being said, I did not do the test, and I think it is very interesting to do, because if we can find a way to help the optimization with sigmoid, we can reduce drastically the number of parameters.